# php array of arrays deep level

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

```
Word-Array
     Words1-array
     Words1 meaning
        -Words1 Synonyms-
             -Synonym1,Synonym2.etc(Array)
        -Words1 Antonyms
             -Antonym1,Antonym2.etc(Array)
    Words2-array
     Words2 meaning
        -Words2 Synonyms-
             -Synonym1,Synonym2.etc(Array)
        -Words2 Antonyms
             -Antonym1,Antonym2.etc(Array)

$ar1 = array(array("Words"=>array("word","meaning","synonyms"=>array(),"antonyms"=array()))));
```

I was trying to create Php Array of Arrays for Generating JSON Result but always failed to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$words = array(
    'word1' => array(
        'meaning' => 'word1 meaning',
        'synonyms' => array(
            'word1 synonym1',
            'word1 synonym2'
        ),
        'antonyms' => array(
            'word1 antonym1',
            'word1 antonym2'
        )
    ),
    'word2' => array(
        'meaning' => 'word2 meaning',
        'synonyms' => array(
            'word2 synonym1',
            'word2 synonym2'
        ),
        'antonyms' => array(
            'word2 antonym1',
            'word2 antonym2'
        )
    )
);
```

If this is what you're looking for, it is pretty straightforward to create such an array dynamically from whatever datasource you have available. Since you haven't provided that information in your question, let's assume you have a MySQL database that's structured like this:

```
                 +----------+
+---------+      | synonyms |
| words   |      +----------+
+---------+      | id       |
| id      | -+-> | word_id  |
| word    |  |   | synonym  |
| meaning |  |   +----------+
+---------+  |
             |   +----------+
             |   | antonyms |
             |   +----------+
             |   | id       |
             \-> | word_id  |
                 | antonym  |
                 +----------+
```

This is of course very simplistic, you'll have a lot of duplicates in the `synonyms` and `antonyms` table with this configuration.

You can use standard `PDO` or `mysqli` functionality to retrieve the information from your database. Since it's not clear whether your datasource is in fact a MySQL-database, I'm going to assume `mysqli` and use very basic queries in this example. After all, the purpose here is not to teach you how to communicate with your database securely, but how to build a multidimensional array you can pass through `json_encode()`. Here's one way you can do that:

```
$words = array();

$mysqli = new mysqli(...);

// retrieve the list of words from the `words` table
$words_res = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM `words`');
while ($word = $words_res->fetch_assoc()) {
    // build the initial sub-array for this word, we'll be adding
    // it to $words after we fill it
    $word_array = array(
        'meaning' => $word['meaning'],
        'synonyms' => array(),
        'antonyms' => array()
    );

    // retrieve all synonyms for this word
    $synonyms_res = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM `synonyms` WHERE `word_id` = ' . $word['id']);
    while ($synonym = $synonyms_res->fetch_assoc()) {
        // add this synonym to our $word_array
        $word_array['synonyms'][] = $synonym['synonym'];
    }

    // retrieve all antonyms for this word
    $antonyms_res = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM `antonyms` WHERE `word_id` = ' . $word['id']);
    while ($antonym = $antonyms_res->fetch_assoc()) {
        // add this antonym to our $word_array
        $word_array['antonyms'][] = $antonym['antonym'];
    }

    // now that $word_array is filled, we can add it to $words
    $words[$word['word']] = $word_array;
}

// since you say you want a JSON result, convert the array to
// JSON and output it
echo json_encode($words);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how to add or update these fields uisng PHP?

Comment: @MithunSudheendran I've added an example

Comment: WOW, you must get at least an upvote for writing great answer, above and beyond from what the OP asked for. There are some improvements that can added (example - using prepared statements) but that is something that the OP should learn.  Good job!

Comment: @AlonEitan Thanks!